How to get an attribute as an integer >= 1 with XPath?
Consider this input:
<tr>
   <td                  />
   <td rowspan="3"      />
   <td rowspan="-2"     />
   <td rowspan="*8#%@!" />
   <td rowspan="5.7"    />
   <td rowspan="-4.3"   />
   <td rowspan="6e1"    />
</tr>

From which I would like to get the rowspan attribute of every td node as an integer >= 1.
The resulting sequence should be:
1
3
1
1
5
1
60


Please provide a specification, not just a set of examples. Is your third number 1 because that's the default, or because you've stripped out the minus sign from the input?

<td rowspan="&#%@!" /> is not well-formed XML.

A possibility is to use the filter [number() = number()] to only select values that are numerical:
//td/( (1, @rowspan[number() = number()]) => max() => xs:integer() )


In XPath 2 and later you can express number() = number() as . castable as xs:double.
